# OrderBy in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this code in Laravel 5.2 returning a list of installers to a drop-down in my view. I can't get it to orderby the using the query below.

I think it is something to do with the join and perhaps it can't order the collection the way it is loaded but I am struggling to fix this.

Can someone suggest a better way to order by using this code?

```
$latest_installers = DB::table('sys_installer_version')
    ->join('sys_installer', 'sys_installer.id', '=', 'sys_installer_version.installer_id')
    ->where('sys_installer.active', '1')
    ->where('sys_installer_version.active', '1')
    ->where('sys_installer_version.latest', '1')
    ->orderBy('sys_installer_version.filename', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Thanks,

Comment: Try to use all conditions in 1 where clause like `where([['sys_installer.active', '=', '1'],
    ['sys_installer_version.active', '=', '1'],['sys_installer_version.latest','=',1]
])`.

Comment: can you replace `->get()` with `->toSql()` and show us the output please? Debugging queries like this is much easier if you have a look at the raw sql the query builder is creating.

Comment: @WaytoDeveloper Thanks, that code is good but found issue and it was not that.

Comment: @Bryan Thank you for suggesting that, I did not debug but remembered I have a package turned on in dev environment that provides all this detail. It turns out the issue was that I was modifying code in one Controller, but the view was using a separate near identical Controller. Updated code with above query in both Controllers and it works now. Thanks for help people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

Code above works fine but my issue was that I was modifying it in the wrong Controller hence it appearing not to be ordering the list when testing.

Updating code in both Controllers has fixed this issue.

We use barryvdh/laravel-debugbar on our dev environment and it helps find and fix these issues.